# How to use sed command to replace word in file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file:

```
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.HOSTNAME=localhost
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.DOMAIN=auth.jc.name.com
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.USERNAME=name
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.PASSWORD=Hfr*7462
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.MUC_JIDS=JvbBredjoy@internal.auth.jc.name.com
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.MUC_NICKNAME=7896aee5-fgre-4b02-4569-0bcc75ed1d0d
```

I created a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DPATH="/etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties"
k=$(grep -o 'shard-1' $DPATH) # shard ends by a number#
i=$(grep -o 'shard-1' $DPATH | cut -c7)
m=$((i+1))
n="shard-$m"
sed -i "s|${k}|${n}|g" $DPATH
```

But I get error:

```
/home/scripts# ./shard_number
./shard_number: line 5: 1
1
1
1
1
1: syntax error in expression (error token is "1
1
1
1
1")
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

Could you please help to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: My  expected output like this... +1
`org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-2.HOSTNAME=localhost
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-2.DOMAIN=auth.jc.name.com
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-2.USERNAME=name
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-.PASSWORD=Hfr*7462
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-2.MUC_JIDS=JvbBredjoy@internal.auth.jc.name.com
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-2.MUC_NICKNAME=7896aee5-fgre-4b02-4569-0bcc75ed1d0d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your script with `bash -x /path/to/your/script` or add `set -x` somewhere at the start of your script (after the `#!shebang`, but before the commands you want to debug), you will see that your `grep` commands return not a single 'shard-1' but rather one 'shard-1' per line :

```
++ grep -o shard-1 /etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties
+ k='shard-1
shard-1
shard-1
shard-1
shard-1
shard-1'
```

Once `cut`, that gives the `1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n` string that is mentionned in your error output as an invalid token for the `$(( ... ))` expression, which also breaks the syntax of your `sed` substitution :

```
++ cut -c7
++ grep -o shard-1 /etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties
+ i='1
1
1
1
1
1'
```

Make that string a single number (for instance piping your `grep` into `sort -u` to unicize all the shards found) and your script will work just fine :

```
#!/bin/bash
DPATH="/etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties"
k=$(grep -o 'shard-1' $DPATH | sort -u) # shard ends by a number#
i=$(grep -o 'shard-1' $DPATH | sort -u | cut -c7)
m=$((i+1))
n="shard-$m"
sed -i "s|${k}|${n}|g" $DPATH
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/GE5uI0). Also check [this test](https://ideone.com/yvbGCM) if you want to see your initial script debugged.

Comment: @Oleg I'm no genius, I'm just someone who suffered through a lot of shell scripting in his life : you eventually learn some tricks to make it less painful ;)

Comment: Sorry, one more question :) What if I need to increase number for one more 1?

from `org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-2.HOSTNAME=localhost` to 
`org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-3.HOSTNAME=localhost` 
Because we will be have more than 1 servers. I think I did not think about it. :)

Comment: Currently you're searching 'shard-1' in the file, which isn't that useful : you're either going to find it and retrieve 'shard-1', or you're not going to find it and your script will fail. Maybe you want to search for `shard-[0-9]+`, which would find shard-2, shard-3, etc. and which make you let you use your script on the result of a previous execution to transform `shard-2` into `shard-3`, `shard-n` into `shard-n+1` ?

Comment: Or if you want to produce multiple shard-n at the same time from the initial `shard-1` file, you will probably want to use some kind of `for` loop. The simple modern `for` loop syntax in `bash` is the c-style `for` loop, `for ((i=0; i<9; i++)) { ... }`

Comment: Ah, regarding `shard-[0-9]+` : you'll need to add the `-E` flag to `grep` for it to work, or write it as `shard-[0-9]\+` if you want to use the anticated Basic Regular Expression syntax

Comment: Super, thank you so much. It works. I think we will not the use more than 9 servers. Because flag `-c7` will not work after number 9 :)
```#!/bin/bash
DPATH="/etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties"
set -x
k=$(grep -o -E 'shard-[0-9]+' $DPATH | sort -u) # shard ends by a number#
i=$(grep -o -E 'shard-[0-9]+' $DPATH | sort -u | cut -c7)
m=$((i+1))
n="shard-$m"
sed -i "s|${k}|${n}|g" $DPATH```

Comment: @Oleg you could use `-` as a separator in your `cut` command and tell it to retrieve the second field

Comment: Could you please help with one more advise :)

By default I have line like this `org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.HOSTNAME=localhost` can I add number `-1`  after `shard` using similar script and then use created scripts to increase numbers?

Comment: @Oleg last one then. We might be depriving a new StackOverflow user from posting his first answer, and I don't like having to face the choice of  either assuming the responsability of answering you or being rude by ignoring your question that noone else will read in these comments. `sed 's/\.shard\./.shard-1./' file`